# Simulate user actions (ex: mouse click) in Swing application without access to source code

Tags: java, swing

Is it possible to simulate user's actions like mouse click in Swing application in case there's no way to get access to source code?

All the ways I found rely on source code of the app.

Comment: You can simulate mouseclicks etc using the java.awt,Robot class, is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Nasty reflection hacks could be possible, but I think the questions lacks details about the actual goals.